# Passing Realm variable to getView in the adapter

Tags: java, android, realm

In my main activity, I like to pass a result value from another class to the processing adapter class.  However, it crashed on me.

The syntax is correct and it can compile but it would crash.
My question is that what is the proper to do it to pass radioPosition from Setting class to the School adaptor of school class

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ....
    Setting setting = realm.where(Setting.class).findFirst();
    //radioPosition is from Setting Class
    Integer radioPosition = setting.getPosition();
    RealmResults<School> schools = realm.where(School.class).findAll();
    //schools is from School Class

    final SchoolAdapter adapter = new SchoolAdapter(this, R.id.schools_list, schools, Integer radioPosition, true);
    ....
   }
```

School Adaptor:

```
public class SchoolAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<School> implements ListAdapter {

....
public SchoolAdapter(Context context, int resId, RealmResults<School> realmResults,  Integer radioPosition, boolean automaticUpdate) {

    super(context, realmResults,  automaticUpdate);

}

  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.school = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

.....
```

Comment: Just repost my logcat.  Thanks.

Comment: I try to add radioPosition to  super(context, realmResults, radioPosition, automaticUpdate);  However, it gave me an error: realmbaseadaptor cannot be apply to context - expected parameter: automatic boolean, actual argument: radioPosition, automatic boolean.  Is there anything I am missing when I pass value from another realm class?

Comment: check your line number 59  in your SchoolAdapter  as per your logcat null exception is there. please check

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   I think I found out my where is my problem...My question should be how to pass realm result  from setting class<radioPosition> to getView so I can use it to get data.  Many Thanks.